# DocuSign Rest API, can't add more than one document?

Tags: c#, vb.net, docusignapi

I'm using the following wrapper for DocuSign API: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client

Everything is fine, as long as I only use a single document. But if I pass in more than one document, it only uses the first one, as in once the link is clicked in the email, the only document visible is the first one:

```vb
Dim envelope As New EnvelopeDefinition(),
        api As New EnvelopesApi()

    With envelope
        .TemplateId = _model.TemplateId
        .EmailSubject = _model.EmailSubject
        .Status = "sent"
    End With


    If _model.Documents IsNot Nothing AndAlso _model.Documents.Count > 0 Then
        Dim documents As New List(Of Document)()
        For Each doc In _model.Documents
            Dim tDoc As New Document()
            With tDoc
                .Name = doc.Name
                .FileExtension = doc.Extension.Replace(".", "")
                .DocumentId = doc.ID
                .DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(doc.FileBytes)
            End With
            documents.Add(tDoc)
        Next
        envelope.Documents = documents
    End If

    If _model.Recipients IsNot Nothing AndAlso _model.Recipients.Count > 0 Then
        Dim templateRoles As New List(Of TemplateRole)()
        For Each recipient In _model.Recipients
            Dim role As New TemplateRole()
            With role
                .Email = recipient.Email
                .Name = recipient.Name
                .RoleName = recipient.RoleName
                .Tabs = New Tabs()
                .Tabs.SignHereTabs = New List(Of SignHere)

                For Each doc In envelope.Documents
                    Dim signHere As New SignHere()
                    With signHere
                        .DocumentId = doc.DocumentId
                        .AnchorString = recipient.AnchorText
                        .AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true"
                    End With
                    .Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere)
                Next

            End With
            templateRoles.Add(role)
        Next recipient
        envelope.TemplateRoles = templateRoles
    End If

    Dim summary As EnvelopeSummary = api.CreateEnvelope(_model.Authentication.AccountID, envelope)
```

C# examples welcome, or VB.NET, or just general help as to what might be the issue.

**-- UPDATE --
Here's the json formatted request:**

```
POST https: 

//demo.docusign.net:7801/restapi/v2/accounts/MYACCOUNTNUMBER/envelopes
Content - Length: 415238
Content - Type: application / json
Accept: application / json
Host: demo.docusign.net
User - Agent: RestSharp / 105.1.0.0
X - DocuSign - SDK: C #
X - DocuSign - Authentication: {
    "Username": "myusername@somewhere.com",
    "Password": "[omitted]",
    "IntegratorKey": "[omitted]"
}
X - Forwarded - For: 55.55.555.555
X - SecurityProtocol - Version: TLSv1
X - SecurityProtocol - CipherSuite: ECDHE - RSA - AES256 - CBC - SHA {
    "documents": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "uri": null,
        "remoteUrl": null,
        "name": "Test1",
        "password": null,
        "transformPdfFields": null,
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "matchBoxes": null,
        "order": null,
        "pages": null,
        "documentFields": null,
        "encryptedWithKeyManager": null,
        "documentBase64": "JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL= ETC ETC",
        "applyAnchorTabs": null
    }, {
        "documentId": "2",
        "uri": null,
        "remoteUrl": null,
        "name": "Test2",
        "password": null,
        "transformPdfFields": null,
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "matchBoxes": null,
        "order": null,
        "pages": null,
        "documentFields": null,
        "encryptedWithKeyManager": null,
        "documentBase64": "JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9U== ETC ETC",
        "applyAnchorTabs": null
    }, {
        "documentId": "3",
        "uri": null,
        "remoteUrl": null,
        "name": "Test3",
        "password": null,
        "transformPdfFields": null,
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "matchBoxes": null,
        "order": null,
        "pages": null,
        "documentFields": null,
        "encryptedWithKeyManager": null,
        "documentBase64": "JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9Ue ETC ETC",
        "applyAnchorTabs": null
    }],
    "recipients": null,
    "customFields": null,
    "eventNotification": null,
    "brandId": null,
    "allowRecipientRecursion": null,
    "templateId": "MYTEMPLATEID",
    "templateRoles": [{
        "email": "MYEMAIL@me.com",
        "roleName": "Customer",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "signingGroupId": null,
        "inPersonSignerName": null,
        "clientUserId": null,
        "embeddedRecipientStartURL": null,
        "defaultRecipient": null,
        "accessCode": null,
        "routingOrder": null,
        "emailNotification": null,
        "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": [{
                "name": null,
                "tabLabel": null,
                "scaleValue": null,
                "optional": null,
                "documentId": "1",
                "recipientId": null,
                "pageNumber": null,
                "xPosition": null,
                "yPosition": null,
                "anchorString": "customeranchor",
                "anchorXOffset": null,
                "anchorYOffset": null,
                "anchorUnits": null,
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorCaseSensitive": null,
                "anchorMatchWholeWord": null,
                "anchorHorizontalAlignment": null,
                "tabId": null,
                "templateLocked": null,
                "templateRequired": null,
                "conditionalParentLabel": null,
                "conditionalParentValue": null,
                "customTabId": null,
                "mergeField": null,
                "status": null,
                "errorDetails": null
            }, {
                "name": null,
                "tabLabel": null,
                "scaleValue": null,
                "optional": null,
                "documentId": "2",
                "recipientId": null,
                "pageNumber": null,
                "xPosition": null,
                "yPosition": null,
                "anchorString": "customeranchor",
                "anchorXOffset": null,
                "anchorYOffset": null,
                "anchorUnits": null,
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorCaseSensitive": null,
                "anchorMatchWholeWord": null,
                "anchorHorizontalAlignment": null,
                "tabId": null,
                "templateLocked": null,
                "templateRequired": null,
                "conditionalParentLabel": null,
                "conditionalParentValue": null,
                "customTabId": null,
                "mergeField": null,
                "status": null,
                "errorDetails": null
            }, {
                "name": null,
                "tabLabel": null,
                "scaleValue": null,
                "optional": null,
                "documentId": "3",
                "recipientId": null,
                "pageNumber": null,
                "xPosition": null,
                "yPosition": null,
                "anchorString": "customeranchor",
                "anchorXOffset": null,
                "anchorYOffset": null,
                "anchorUnits": null,
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorCaseSensitive": null,
                "anchorMatchWholeWord": null,
                "anchorHorizontalAlignment": null,
                "tabId": null,
                "templateLocked": null,
                "templateRequired": null,
                "conditionalParentLabel": null,
                "conditionalParentValue": null,
                "customTabId": null,
                "mergeField": null,
                "status": null,
                "errorDetails": null
            }],
            "initialHereTabs": null,
            "signerAttachmentTabs": null,
            "approveTabs": null,
            "declineTabs": null,
            "fullNameTabs": null,
            "dateSignedTabs": null,
            "envelopeIdTabs": null,
            "companyTabs": null,
            "titleTabs": null,
            "textTabs": null,
            "numberTabs": null,
            "ssnTabs": null,
            "dateTabs": null,
            "zipTabs": null,
            "emailTabs": null,
            "noteTabs": null,
            "checkboxTabs": null,
            "radioGroupTabs": null,
            "listTabs": null,
            "firstNameTabs": null,
            "lastNameTabs": null,
            "emailAddressTabs": null,
            "formulaTabs": null
        }
    }, {
        "email": null,
        "roleName": "Account Manager",
        "name": null,
        "signingGroupId": null,
        "inPersonSignerName": null,
        "clientUserId": null,
        "embeddedRecipientStartURL": null,
        "defaultRecipient": null,
        "accessCode": null,
        "routingOrder": null,
        "emailNotification": null,
        "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": [{
                "name": null,
                "tabLabel": null,
                "scaleValue": null,
                "optional": null,
                "documentId": "1",
                "recipientId": null,
                "pageNumber": null,
                "xPosition": null,
                "yPosition": null,
                "anchorString": "adminanchor",
                "anchorXOffset": null,
                "anchorYOffset": null,
                "anchorUnits": null,
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorCaseSensitive": null,
                "anchorMatchWholeWord": null,
                "anchorHorizontalAlignment": null,
                "tabId": null,
                "templateLocked": null,
                "templateRequired": null,
                "conditionalParentLabel": null,
                "conditionalParentValue": null,
                "customTabId": null,
                "mergeField": null,
                "status": null,
                "errorDetails": null
            }, {
                "name": null,
                "tabLabel": null,
                "scaleValue": null,
                "optional": null,
                "documentId": "2",
                "recipientId": null,
                "pageNumber": null,
                "xPosition": null,
                "yPosition": null,
                "anchorString": "adminanchor",
                "anchorXOffset": null,
                "anchorYOffset": null,
                "anchorUnits": null,
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorCaseSensitive": null,
                "anchorMatchWholeWord": null,
                "anchorHorizontalAlignment": null,
                "tabId": null,
                "templateLocked": null,
                "templateRequired": null,
                "conditionalParentLabel": null,
                "conditionalParentValue": null,
                "customTabId": null,
                "mergeField": null,
                "status": null,
                "errorDetails": null
            }, {
                "name": null,
                "tabLabel": null,
                "scaleValue": null,
                "optional": null,
                "documentId": "3",
                "recipientId": null,
                "pageNumber": null,
                "xPosition": null,
                "yPosition": null,
                "anchorString": "adminanchor",
                "anchorXOffset": null,
                "anchorYOffset": null,
                "anchorUnits": null,
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorCaseSensitive": null,
                "anchorMatchWholeWord": null,
                "anchorHorizontalAlignment": null,
                "tabId": null,
                "templateLocked": null,
                "templateRequired": null,
                "conditionalParentLabel": null,
                "conditionalParentValue": null,
                "customTabId": null,
                "mergeField": null,
                "status": null,
                "errorDetails": null
            }],
            "initialHereTabs": null,
            "signerAttachmentTabs": null,
            "approveTabs": null,
            "declineTabs": null,
            "fullNameTabs": null,
            "dateSignedTabs": null,
            "envelopeIdTabs": null,
            "companyTabs": null,
            "titleTabs": null,
            "textTabs": null,
            "numberTabs": null,
            "ssnTabs": null,
            "dateTabs": null,
            "zipTabs": null,
            "emailTabs": null,
            "noteTabs": null,
            "checkboxTabs": null,
            "radioGroupTabs": null,
            "listTabs": null,
            "firstNameTabs": null,
            "lastNameTabs": null,
            "emailAddressTabs": null,
            "formulaTabs": null
        }
    }],
    "compositeTemplates": null,
    "accessibility": null,
    "transactionId": null,
    "status": "sent",
    "documentsUri": null,
    "recipientsUri": null,
    "asynchronous": null,
    "envelopeUri": null,
    "emailSubject": "Test DocuSign - Hello World",
    "emailBlurb": null,
    "envelopeId": null,
    "signingLocation": null,
    "customFieldsUri": null,
    "envelopeIdStamping": null,
    "authoritativeCopy": null,
    "notification": null,
    "notificationUri": null,
    "enforceSignerVisibility": null,
    "enableWetSign": null,
    "allowMarkup": null,
    "allowReassign": null,
    "createdDateTime": null,
    "lastModifiedDateTime": null,
    "deliveredDateTime": null,
    "sentDateTime": null,
    "completedDateTime": null,
    "voidedDateTime": null,
    "voidedReason": null,
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    "declinedDateTime": null,
    "statusChangedDateTime": null,
    "documentsCombinedUri": null,
    "certificateUri": null,
    "templatesUri": null,
    "messageLock": null,
    "recipientsLock": null,
    "useDisclosure": null,
    "emailSettings": null,
    "purgeState": null,
    "lockInformation": null,
    "is21CFRPart11": null
}
201 Created
Content - Type: application / json;
charset = utf - 8 {
    "envelopeId": "555555555555555555",
    "uri": "/envelopes/adsfadsfadsfasdfadsfadsfasdf",
    "statusDateTime": "2016-06-30T22:22:31.5900000Z",
    "status": "sent"
}
```

**Additional**:

I'm able to attach more than one document when not using a template. When using a template, I cannot. Even if I add the same amount of documents in the template, it does not work.

I have been able to make this work, but it doesn't seem correct. The way I've been able to make it work is with composite and inline templates.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you could post the raw JSON that your VB code produces (you can redact any private info if present).  You can use request logging through your account preferences or a tool like Fiddler to capture the raw API request.

Comment: @Ergin Please see updated question. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think the system is acting as expected, see my answer below.  Composite Templates is indeed the way to combine templates and documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your updated post, which specifies that you can get multiple documents working but not when you send through a template, the system is acting as designed and there's no bug here.

I think you've basically answered your own question, if you want to combine a template and additional documents, or two or more templates together, or any other combination of templates and documents then yes you need to use the `compositeTemplates` node.

Here's some additional resources for composite templates:

- [Developer Center - Templates Explanation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/templates#composite)
- [API Docs - Envelope Create API](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) (see Composite Templates section further down)
- [GitHub Sample](https://github.com/Ergin008/DocuSign-REST-API-Webinar-April2013/) (see the third sample which combines two templates)

Answer (score 0):

As Ergin says in his comment, the platform reacts to the incoming API call, so you need to show the incoming API request itself to get the best answer.

Here is a [blog post on obtaining the API log](https://www.docusign.com/blog/checking-api-logs-like-the-weather/).

In the meantime, here are some ideas:

1. Ensure that the documentId is different for the two documents.
2. **An example:** Look at the [multiple documents recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/send-multiple-docs) to see how multiple documents do work
3. If your documents are especially large (>20MB or so), then you may be exceeding the max call size. Solution: first create the envelope in draft mode with one document, then add the second doc via a separate call.

Comment: I was able to obtain the logging. Please see updated answer. Thank you!

Comment: I think you're on to something here... files aren't big, so not sure what's going on, but created as draft and adding documents one at a time seems to be working so far. Will update as I continue

Comment: Okay this works, but on comes another issue. My signing tabs are broken afterwards.

Comment: Compositing templates and documents together is tricky. You may want to just specify everything in your call and not use a template at all. See the multiple documents recipe I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(doc.FileBytes) use following function:
.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(ReadContent(doc))

```
Private Function ReadContent(ByVal fileName As String) As Byte()
    Dim tempByte() As Byte = Nothing
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("FileName Not Provided")
        Return Nothing
    End If
    Try
        Dim fileInfo As New FileInfo(fileName)
        Dim numBytes As Long = fileInfo.Length
        Dim fStream As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim binaryReader As New BinaryReader(fStream)
        tempByte = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(numBytes))
        fileInfo = Nothing
        numBytes = 0
        fStream.Close()
        fStream.Dispose()
        Return tempByte
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function
```